# How to check if the level of data is correct in SQL?

Tags: sql, primary-key

I have a table with certain columns in it. I want to find out the level of data(composition of columns which can uniquely identify a row) in that table. Is there some SQL query which can help me to do this?

I am new to SQL and I thought of this approach but I cannot frame the query.

1. Group the data by the columns you think are the primary key
2. Count the number of rows in this grouped data
3. If this number is equal to the number of rows in the initial table, then it is the primary key

Could you help me with the query?

Comment: Do you mean: how can I check if the set of columns I would like to be PK uniquely identifies all the rows?

Comment: Point 3 is not necessarily true. Just because they are unique now doesn't guarantee they are unique for all time. Is there currently a primary key?

Comment: `SELECT col1, col2, col3, COUNT(*) FROM your table GROUP BY col1, col2, col3 HAVING COUNT(*) > 1` will return the non-unique records. If you need more help, edit the question to tag the proper RDBMS, and add a sample of data.

Comment: @Richard yes i mean to do that

Comment: @UnhandledExcepSean I don't know the primary key even if it exists. I want to find that out given a table.

Comment: If you script out the definition of the table, you should be able to see if there is already a primary key. I think your approach of finding a combination of columns that produces a unique set is dangerous.

Comment: The designers *declare* column sets whose subrow values are unique per table (and don't contain smaller unique column sets). (Ie CKs.) (Via PK & UNIQUE NOT NULL constraint declarations.) The declarations are recorded in metadata tables. Do you not want this data? What exactly are you assuming about tables that allows you to extract?/infer?/guess? exactly what from them? Do you understand that a table value cannot tell you the CKs of a base table holding it, but can only suggest some possible CKs & tell you some non-CKs? PS Why did you choose the term "level of data"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given `create table T (A number, B number, C number)`, then you can execute this:

```
select  count(*)
       ,count(distinct A || ';' || B || ';' || C)
       ,count(distinct A)
       ,count(distinct B)
       ,count(distinct C)
       ,count(distinct A || ';' || B)
       ,count(distinct B || ';' || C)
       ,count(distinct A || ';' || C)
from T
```

This has the benefit of visiting the rows only once.

If the data types are character then you have to carefully choose a separator character.

But let's say you have a table like what the U. S. government might have had in 1936 that related social security numbers to citizens (um, taxable people, LOL).

At that time, the numbers would not have been reused and so your query would have indicated that SSN is sufficient to uniquely identify a row.

Of course, we know that SSN plus birth date (or is it something else?) is the correct key. But looking only at the data using an arbitrary algorithm is probably not going to work if the table can change.